# Confused about the ?: operator

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (!codeText.StartsWith("<p>"))
{
    codeText = string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");
}
```

How can I make it use the `?:` operator?

Comment: Why would you use the ternary operator in this case ? You have no 'else', so it's quite useless to want to (ab)use the ternary operator.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you think that one line performs better?

Comment: There is no point in calling `string.Concat` here; you should just use the `+` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
codeText = codeText.StartsWith("<p>") ?
               codeText :
               string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the conditional operator needs an `else` clause, you need to tell it to use the original value:

```
codeText = codeText.StartsWith("<p>") ? codeText : "<p>" + codeText + "</p>";
```

However, there is no point in doing this; it's just more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't make much sense to use the ternary operator. I would just stick with the if statement you have now. Typically you would use the ternary operator in an assignment statement or somewhere that you can't use a typical if statement.

However, if you really want to, you could do it like this.

```
codeText = !codeText.StartsWith("<p>") ? string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>") : codeText;
```

Here's the MSDN page for the ternary operator.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

variable = condition ? value if condition is true : value if condition is false

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

`codeText = codeText.StartsWith("<p>") ? codeText : string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");`

If it's fairly long, I usually write it across multiple lines like this:

```
codeText = codeText.StartsWith("<p>")
  ? codeText
  : string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");
```

although I have to admit, I don't see the benefit to using the ?: operator here, given that you don't have an else case, you're having to add one that does `codeText = codeText` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
codeText = (!codeText.StartsWith("<p>")?string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>"):codeText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
codeText = codeText.StartsWith("<p>")
    ? codetext
    : string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");
```

But I'm not sure why would you do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*if*/ condition
     /*then*/? statement1
     /*else*/: statement2
```

so, basically this if construction:

```
if(condition){
    //statement1
}else{
    //statement2
}
```

can be written like :

```
condition 
    ? statement1
    : statement2;
```